# Discord.py | Error with the voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The purpose of this code is that when a participant joins a certain voice channel, his personal voice channel is created. And when the voice channel remains empty, it is automatically deleted. The code performs its task perfectly, but I get an error in the console. How can I solve this?

Code:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    if after.channel.id == 826351221145206855:
        for guild in Bot.guilds:
            maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=816323445213626368)
            channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'HALL {member.display_name}',category = maincategory)
            await channel2.set_permissions(member,connect=True,mute_members=True,move_members=True,manage_channels=True)
            await member.move_to(channel2)
            def check(x, y, z):
                return len(channel2.members) == 0
            await Bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
            await channel2.delete()
```

Error in the console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Маки\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\import discord.py", line 242, in on_voice_state_update
    if after.channel.id == 826351221145206855:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: error shows that `after.channel` is `None`. First you could use `print()` to see what you have in `after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member leaves a voice channel, a `voice_state_update` event will be fired and `after.channel` will be `None`, because the user no longer is in any voice channel. Therefore, your first `if`-statement evaluates to

```py
if None.id == 826351221145206855:
```

and produces the error you see. A clean fix is to modify the line to

```py
if after.channel and after.channel.id == 826351221145206855:
```

This way, your bot will first check if the user even is in a voice channel and only try to look at the id if that is the case. This utilizes the Python mechanic that `if None` evaluates to `False` while `if "actual channel"` evaluates to `True` and won't interfere with the rest of your code as well, since no new action is required when a user leaves any voice channels